# Orbot, Change Identity Remote (On Same Device Different App)

Tags: orbot, android

i am thinking to write a apk. i will use orbot proxy (127.0.0.1:8118). i can change tor identity on ubuntu (sudo service tor restart). my question is;

can i change orbot (tor) identity from my apk on same device?

(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - it's not dependent on APK or other package-style stuff. Just use Tor control protocol and do whatever you need to do over network

Comment: It's often easier to use SOCKS and change the password to get a new circuit. Take a look at [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14457/how-many-local-concurrent-tor-connections-can-i-run/14459#14459).